# Visual Studio 2013 Codelens just inserts blank line

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, codelens

I'm having an issue with CodeLens in Visual Studio 2013. I recently upgraded Visual Studio 2013 Profession to Ultimate. I have CodeLens turned on:

[image: CodeLens]

But for some reason, Visual Studio is just inserting a blank line where the "references" should go:

[image]

You can see the blank line between lines 79 and 80. It does this with every project and every class in any project I open.

Does anyone know what could cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seemed to fix itself when I upgraded to Visual Studio 2013 Update 5, released on 7/20/2015. My CodeLens now works as expected and shows information rather than a blank line.

Answer (score 0):

These are not simply "blank lines", at least they shouldn't be.

This is the space that CodeLens reserves for its information. As you [see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn269218.aspx), there is small text above the declaration for information like "2 references".
If you open a project, it will reserve this space (because it knows it will need it later) before it can actually display this information (because the full project scan takes time, more time the larger the project is)

Now, load a small project and wait a little for the info to appear. (Have an eye on the task manager while doing nothing.) If it does not appear, something might be wrong with the IDE. Maybe the text color is white on white? Try resetting the settings.

Comment: I reset my default settings. Still nothing. Also, no matter how small a project I load, I still never get the CodeLens info. Its still blank lines. Even a simple Console "Hello World" program doesn't do it.

Comment: Have you tried repairing Visual Studio? Or (re-)applying the latest Visual Studio Update?